# Watch for changes and reload Kestrel during development with ASP .NET 5 RC1

Tags: asp.net, gulp, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I tried the new dnx-watch web, it didn't do anything when changing files. Found a package called nodemon, which will watch the tree and restart dnx web just fine. This is doing what I assume dnx-watch web will eventually do, but when dnx web is restarted, its slow as molasses. Just as slow as when the dnx web call is on first run. Has anyone found a friendly and fast way to develop with this new stack. This is RC 1 and there is no real developer friendly workflow. Please tell me I'm just missing step X. Thanks!

*Workflow clarity: I primarily work on front-end files, namely less, JS and cshtml views. I use gulp to process these changes via watch and perform injections of the resulting outputs, so in the end, I'm only changing static files moreorless. Having to restart dnx web each time for this is painfully slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working only on `*.js`/`*.css`/`*.cshtml`, then you do not need to restart DNX.

You could just have your `gulp:min` task and be on your merry way (if you even need it). I would definitely add another task to do `bower install`/`npm install` when their respective file change however. That would help you a lot.

If you want to restart DNX, I would only restart it when a `cs` file change.

**UPDATE about the removal of design time cshtml compilation**

Alright... so... I went to http://github.com/aspnet/dnx and looked for the relevant bugs for you. There was [bugs](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/1912) that mentioned that `cshtml` wouldn't work when updated and the fix was [to include an IFileWatcher](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/commit/f1b13799a4e165147827ebecb8dff00f6f48e677). This was all fine and pretty until about `beta5` where it was removed and postponed to `beta8`, then `rc1`, `backlog`, `rc1`, `rc2`.

So... the final answer? It ain't working right now but they know they have to deliver it. So... that's it.

It's broken at the moment.

Comment: I wish this was working... changing these items do not update unless I restart the server. :(

Comment: Do you have a `app.UseStaticFiles(...)` somewhere in your `Startup.cs`? If you do, it should do only one thing, serve them from the `wwwroot` folder. It does not track if those files changed or not. It serves them.

Comment: yes, app.UseStaticFiles is being called. This is the starter project template with RC1.

Comment: part of my injection process replaces Views/Home/Index.cshtml and Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml from a different source location. These seem to be the files that are not serving updated versions.

Comment: added more info after researching the subject for you

Comment: Thank you for that research, it is very much appreciated!